# How do i select the most recent datetime from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched around but can't find the answer I'm looking for.

I have two tables, each has a date field called last_update_date. I want to search which of the two tables has the most recent date and only return that date.

I tried this query hoping it will order the two tables last_update_date field and return that result but the query does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

"Select last_update_date from Table1, Table2 order by last_update_date DESC Limit 1"

Comment: Are there any references to other tables or anything to join on?  You could do a UNION ALL on both tables and select max date from those.  Do you have any identifier on the tabels you want or just the lastupdate date itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(last_update_date)
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(last_update_date) as last_update_date
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(last_update_date)
    FROM Table2
) tMax
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I have to start by apologizing for not being more specific. This works perfectly when I run the query. The problem is I'm trying to put the statement in a PHP PDO statement. I get a blank return when I did this
 $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT MAX(last_update_date) FROM (
     SELECT MAX(last_update_date) as last_update_date
     FROM Table1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT MAX(last_update_date)
     FROM Table2
     ) tMax");
   
   
   $sql->execute();
   $results = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $extract_date = $results['last_update_date'];
   
   echo $extract_date;

Comment: Got it, I had to switch $results['last_update_date'] to $results['MAX(last_udpate_date')] . Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
( select last_update_date from table1 
  UNION ALL 
  select last_update_date from table2 
) order by last_update_date;
```

Comment: If MySQL has max, maybe selecting max(last_update_date) from each one still using union, so you are not selecting every record from both tables prior to getting max date

Comment: Yes, you are 100% right, getting the max from both tables would make it much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(A.last_update_date) 
 (SELECT last_update_date FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT last_update_date FROM Table2) A;
```